# EV3 T Rex problems

Tags: ev3

I am new to this and I need some help with  the moveabsolute block which is described in Chapter 16 of Daniele Benedetelli's book. In figure 16 - 2 he describes the block and here is my problem: I cannot find the first symbol all the way to the left in figure 16-2 . I believe it is called  "connection " or "connector" .   Right of that symbol  is the symbol "speed" followed "degree" and "brake"

Where do I find this symbol  "connection or connector"?
Where do I find this block or do I have to assemble it myself ?
If I have to assemble that block myself - how do I do that ?

Comment: Is there any chance you could include a picture of the figure in question?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Figure 16-2]

*The Lego Mindstorms EV3 Laboratory* by **Daniele Benedettelli**

1. Open / create the EV3 program for the T-Rex
2. add the **motor rotation**, **math** and **large motor** blocks to your program. Don't search for the first block.
3. Select the 3 blocks you just added.
4. Select *My Block Builder* under *tools* menu. You get a new window
5. Give the block a name.
6. In the top half of the screen click the button *add or edit* parameters 4 times (4 Connections)
7. On the **parameter setup** tab you must changes the values according the book.
8. Under **Parameter Icons** tab you can add some icons to the different parameters.
9. When finished select the finish button

Now the My Block will be created and opened. Here you see that the first connection block is added. Now you can add the different signal lines.

In your main / used program the 3 blocks are replaced by your My Block

Comment: Thanks a lot Zeph and Joost ! Unfortunately I cannot add a picture.

Comment: Loost, could you explain a little more detailed what you mean by "...add the different blocks you want in your MyBlock to the editing screen, select them"   My problem that I cannot find that symbol  "connection, or connector "  which is displayed in figure 16 -2

Comment: Joost, could you explain a little more detailed what you mean by "...add the different blocks you want in your MyBlock to the editing screen, select them"   My problem that I cannot find that symbol  "connection, or connector "  which is displayed in figure 16 -2   You can also explain in German if that makes it easier , thank you again !

Comment: I tried to clarify my answer. I hope this will explain how to create the My Block and how you get the connection block

Comment: Joost,  thank you very much for answering so detailed. Great help !! I will try your steps and let you know how it works.